# javascript – how to fade out a class after 100vh scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The Function is working well but i want to fade out the element after a 100vh scroll instead of a 500px scroll.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 500 ){jQuery(".test").fadeIn( 100 );}
    else{jQuery(".test").fadeOut( 100 );}});
```

Answer (score 2):

100vh = `$( window ).height();`

So just use this value insted of 500px

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code for that, may be it work for you

```
 jQuery(function() {
  var getWindow = jQuery(window);
  var windowHeight = getWindow.height(); 
  jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
   if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > windowHeight ){jQuery(".test").fadeIn( 100 );}
   else{jQuery(".test").fadeOut( 100 );}
  });
 });
```

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(window).height()` as a close approximation of `100vh`.

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height()) {
            $('div').fadeIn(100);
        }
    
        else {
            $('div').fadeOut(100);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
height: 200vh;
}

div {
position: relative;
top: 150vh;
left: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
<div></div>
</main>
```